# https://registry.npmjs.org/ url is not opened

Tags: node.js, networking, network-programming, hosting, host

I am trying to installing bootstrap in my laptop using "npm install bootstrap". But i got an error like "request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org".

Finally i notice that, "https://registry.npmjs.org" url is not opening in my browser. so that i couldn't able to install bootstrap. I am using office laptop in my home to install it. Please help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Narasaiah p